# How to get the inline command launch by eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to see what Eclipse executes on the command-line when launching my Java program. How can I access this?

For example, to run myClass.class, Eclipse will use something similar to this: `java.exe -classpath "H:\Eclipse_workspace\Example1\bin;.... myClass.class`. Is there a way to get this command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [RuntimeMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html) within the application that is launched by eclipse.

```
RuntimeMXBean RuntimemxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
List<String> paramList=new ArrayList<String>();
paramList.addAll( RuntimemxBean.getInputArguments() );
paramList.add(  RuntimemxBean.getClassPath() );
paramList.add(  RuntimemxBean.getBootClassPath()  );
paramList.add(  RuntimemxBean.getLibraryPath()  );

for( String p : paramList ) {
    System.out.println( p ); 
}
```

Answer (score 36):

If you're using a launch configuration, you can follow these steps to get the Java command executed by Eclipse to run your program with that configuration:

1. Run the program with the specific launch configuration

   1. Right click the Main class
   2. Select *Run As* > *Run Configurations...*
   3. Setup the configuration to your needs
   4. Click *apply* and then *run*
2. Switch to the Debug perspective (*Window* > *Open Perspective* > *Debug*)
3. In Debug perspective, find the window pane titled *Debug*
4. In the Debug window pane, find the line for the Virtual Machine 
   [image]
5. Right-click the Virtual Machine and select *Properties*
6. In *Process Properties* there is the *Command Line* section which contains exactly the command that Eclipse used to run your program.

Comment: thanks, stupid question (just beginning with eclipse), where is the virtual machine line in the debug view ?

Comment: @scsin75, in the Debug window there is a tree that shows your currently running app, with the `continue, pause, stop, step over, step into` etc buttons

Comment: +1, this is exactly how to get the (**long**) Java command used by Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're seeking and when, you might find it sufficient to view the run configuration, accessible via *Run>Run Configurations.* It identifies what JRE is being used, the program and VM arguments, the classpath, and more.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Windows...

For Linux / Mac OS X, I use something like `ps -x | grep java`, this will show the complete command including class path and arguments, for instance.

Comment: You can actually see it in windows too:  In process explorer you can add the column that shows the full path.