# Eclipse error logs when generating a WSDL

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, wsdl

I create my SOAP services contract-first i.e. I define my class and then generate my WSDL definition off of that. I use the Eclipse utility to do that i.e. right-click the annotated class and then Web Services->Create Web Service. Eclipse then generates the WSDL files and places them in the wsdl folder for that project.

The problem is that if, for some reason, generating the WSDL files fails, there is no way for me to tell why they failed. There is no error message, no logs, nothing. The only way for me to figure out why something failed is for me to manually inspect code.

Is there a better way? Are some error logs being generated that I don't know about?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439068/how-to-get-the-inline-command-launch-by-eclipse/3451722#3451722) how to see which command eclipse is effectively running and run it in a prompt.
In this way, you should be able to see what is going wrong.